# Three.js: texture loaded unproperly

Tags: three.js, textures

I use some data to create a model in three.js. It can load texture, but with a weird problem. I load the texture in this way.

```
`function createMesh(geom, imageFile){
     var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
     texture = loader.load(imageFile); 
     var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
         side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
     });
    mat.map = texture;
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
    return mesh;}
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
    geom.vertices = vertices;
    geom.faces = faces;
    geom.computeFaceNormals();
    var myModel = createMesh(geom, './tex1.jpg');
    scene.add(myModel);`
```

Here is the screenshot before the texture is loaded.

[image]

Here is the screenshot after the texture is loaded.

[image]

My texture file(2048*2048.jpg)

[image]

I have tested to load the texture in a common cube, and it works. So I can't figure out why the texture can't be loaded in my model. Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: To use a texture, you'll want to use [UV Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping). For `Geometry`, this means you'll need to set [`Geometry.faceVertexUvs`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry.faceVertexUvs) with your UV values.

Comment: I have solved it after I added UV Mapping. Thank you very much!

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, please share what you did to correct your issue as an Answer, and include the code you applied to make it work. You can then accept your answer to indicate the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For customized geometry in Three.js, we need to do UV mapping to define how texture is mapped to the geometry.

Firstly, load the texture by `var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture.jpg') } );`

Then here is how I did UV mapping:

1. create n arrarys, each corresponding to a sub-image of the texture and contains 4 points which define the boudaries of the sub-image. (0, 0) represents the lower left corner and (1, 1) represents the upper right corner.
2. clear the existed UV mapping by `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];`
3. Map the sub-image of the texture to each triangle face of the geometry.
   `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [ sub_image_1[0], sub_image_1[1], sub_image_1[3] ];
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = [ sub_image_1[1], sub_image_1[2], sub_image_1[3] ];`

Finally, `mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,  material);`